# Whats the Maven dependency

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to run the Apache Beam Cookbook examples , there is a import statement.

```
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO;
```

What is the maven dependency that my eclipse project needs for this , there is no documentation that I can find.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Maven artifact is called `beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform`, found via [this page](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/681/files) by googling for `org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO`. That is, use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
    <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

for the currently latest version.

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
    <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Please add the above dependency code snippet in your pom.xml file, which will resolve the BigQueryIO class not found exception.
For version number, please go to advanced search in the apache maven website to get the latest version number.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Add this for apache beam

```
         <!--  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.beam/beam-sdks-java-core -->

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
<artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
<version>0.3.0-incubating</version>
</dependency>
```

here is the link for reference

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.beam/beam-sdks-java-core/0.3.0-incubating

Answer (score -2):

The above import statement is for making your utilities package private. You will need that. And coming to the maven dependency, your project might need resources like plugins from various repositories. These resources are managed by maven. You can get maven repositories in your project.

Source:
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html